# How to create a Hulu or IMDB style ViewPager in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've only been learning android for a few days now (beginner) and I'm quite not able to create a ViewPager as fine as these:

[image]

Is it possible to create a ViewPager inside a Fragment. If so any clue on how to proceed with creating such?

As a side note can some also please answer this question: I read somewhere that nested Fragments are possible, is that how these apps are created?

Answer (score 1):

could you put a `ViewPager` in a fragmnet? Yes, Is this what they are doing? I dont know.

Quick example of setting up nested fragments is [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)

It could be an activity with a viewpager at the top in a scrollview too

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. You have to use ViewFlipper and have multiple layouts within that PageViewer, each will be a "page." Here is a good tutorial on how to use this.

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/